# Jquery show and hide border in divs

Tags: jquery, addclass

I try show borders in divs when i click in one and hide in the other in each click

**CSS CODE**

```
 <style>
  .active
     {
     border:4px solid red;
     }
 </style>
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
<script>
function remove(idimg)
{   
    jQuery(".img_f"+idimg).click(function() 
    {   
        jQuery(this).removeClass('active')  
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');            
    }); 
}
</script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="img_f1"></div>
<script>remove('1')</script>
<div class="img_f2"></div>
<script>remove('2')</script>
<div class="img_f3"></div>
<script>remove('3')</script>
<div class="img_f4"></div>
<script>remove('4')</script>
<div class="img_f5"></div>
<script>remove('5')</script>
```

The problem it´s that when i click over the first element show red border and when i do click over second element also show red border but no hide until element border

I don´t know how i can do this for fix and works finally

Tha best regards and thank´s for the help

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're removing the class from the same item you're about to add it to...

Try this:

```
<script>
function remove(idimg)
{   
    jQuery(".img_f"+idimg).click(function() 
    {   
        jQuery('[class^="img_"]').removeClass('active')  
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');            
    }); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to remove the `active` class from the current element, you want to remove it from the previously active element. So it should be:

```
function remove(idimg)
{   
    jQuery(".img_f"+idimg).click(function() 
    {   
        jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');            
    }); 
}
```

BTW, repeatedly calling `remove()` is a poor design. Give all your elements the *same*  class, and then just do this once:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.img_f').click(function() {
    jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img_f">1</div>
<div class="img_f">2</div>
<div class="img_f">3</div>
<div class="img_f">4</div>
<div class="img_f">5</div>
```

Comment: ..except "('.img_f')" won't match anything he has in his html :(

Comment: you'd want ('[class^="img_f"]')

Comment: I meant to give them the same class. I've clarified the answer.

Comment: @Carlos Torres this is better way

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<script>
        function remove(idimg)
        {
            jQuery(".img_f"+idimg).click(function()
            {
                jQuery('div').removeClass('active')
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            });
        }
</script>
```

You can do it more specific way like this

```
jQuery('[class*=img_f]').removeClass('active');
```

or

```
jQuery('div[class*=img_f]').removeClass('active');
```

or

```
jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
```

or

```
jQuery('div.active').removeClass('active');
```

or

```
jQuery('div[class*=img_f].active').removeClass('active');
```